# Is the density of PixelCNN normalized?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing, computer-vision, generative-models

[PixelCNN++](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05517.pdf) constructs a model distribution $p(x)$ over images $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as a product of conditional distributions over pixels

$$p(x)=p(x_1,...,x_{n^2})=\prod_{i=1}^{n^2} p(x_i| x_1,...,x_{i-1})$$

In particular, we choose to model $p(x_i| x_1,...,x_{i-1})$ as a logistic distribution $L(\mu_i, s_i)$ where $\mu_i, s_i = neural\_net_\theta(x_1,...,x_{i-1})$ for parameters $\theta$. The authors claim that $p(x)$ is a probability density distribution, i.e.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} p(x) \; dx=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} 
\prod_{i=1}^{n^2} L( neural\_net_\theta(x_1,...,x_{i-1})) \; dx=1$$

**Q1.** How can we guarantee that this integral is 1 for any neural network?

**Q2.** Is it true for any continuous function?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both questions follows basic probability definitions. Consider a discrete distribution over $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)\in\{0,1\}^2$. The equation then becomes

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{ \mathbf{x} \in \{0,1\}^2 } p(\mathbf{x})  &= \sum_{ x_1 \in \{0,1\} }\sum_{x_2\in\{0,1\}} p(x_1)\cdot p(x_2|x_1) \\
&=\sum_{ x_1 \in \{0,1\} }p(x_1)\cdot \sum_{x_2\in\{0,1\}} p(x_2|x_1) \\
&=\sum_{ x_1 \in \{0,1\} }p(x_1) \cdot  1 \\
&=1
\end{align}$$

So the answer to both questions

**A1.** Expand the equation using basic definitions of probability. Start with simpler example as done above for clarity.

**A2.** As long as the continues function allows us to use the above proof we are fine.